# Обновление данных в Yandex maps api

Tags: javascript, html, xml, yandex-maps-api

Не обновляются данные в yandex map api 2.1 при изменении xml файла.
Разметка:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Примеры YMapsML. Добавление метки на карту.</title>
        <meta htt

p-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- Если вы используете API локально, то в URL ресурса необходимо указывать протокол в стандартном виде (http://...)-->
        <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ymapsml_simpleobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            html, body, #map {
                width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
        ymaps.ready(init);

    function init () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 8
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            });

        // После того как данные YmapsMl-файла загрузятся, вызывается callback-функция.
        ymaps.geoXml.load('data.xml')
            .then(function (res) {
                // Добавляем коллекцию геообъектов на карту.
                myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
            }, function (error) {
                alert('При загрузке YMapsML-файла произошла ошибка: ' + error);
            });
    }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

XML файл:

```
<ymaps xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/ymaps/1.x/ymaps.xsd"> 
    <Representation xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/representation/1.x"> 

        <Style gml:id="commonStyle">
            <iconStyle>
                <size x="60" y="60"/>
                <offset x="-16" y="-18"/>
            </iconStyle>

            <balloonContentStyle> 
                <template>#balloonTemplate</template> 
            </balloonContentStyle> 
        </Style>

<Style gml:id="styleHotels">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/hotel.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleTrain">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/train.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleInternetcafe">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/internet.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleCafe">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/coffee.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleCinema">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/cinema.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleMuseum">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/museum.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleParks">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/parks.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleShips">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/ships.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleTheater">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/theater.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleTurism">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>img/all.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>

<Style gml:id="styleFitness">
<parentStyle>#commonStyle</parentStyle>
<iconStyle>
<href>http://webmap-blog.ru/examples/ymap-ymapsml/images/fitness.png</href>
</iconStyle>
</Style>        

        <Template gml:id="balloonTemplate"> 
            <text><![CDATA[
            <div style="font-size:12px;"> 
                        <div style="color:#ff0303;font-weight:bold">$[name]</div>                        
                        <div>Адрес: $[metaDataProperty.AnyMetaData.adres|не задан]</div>
                        <div>Телефон: $[metaDataProperty.AnyMetaData.telefon|не задан]</div>  
                        <div>Тип: $[metaDataProperty.AnyMetaData.type|не задан]</div>   
                    </div>]]></text> 
        </Template> 
    </Representation> 

    <GeoObjectCollection> 
        <gml:name>Объекты карте</gml:name> 
        <gml:featureMembers><GeoObject gml:id="5"><gml:name>ОАО СЕДЬМОЙ ФЕСТИВАЛЬНАЯ</gml:name><gml:metaDataProperty><AnyMetaData><adres>МОСКВА,ФЕСТИВАЛЬНАЯ УЛ,Д 8 СТР 1</adres><telefon>8960706612</telefon><type>Пиво</type></AnyMetaData></gml:metaDataProperty><gml:Point><gml:pos>55.858807 37.491989</gml:pos></gml:Point><style>#styleHotels</style></GeoObject>
<GeoObject gml:id="1"><gml:name>101 страна отпусков-НН</gml:name><gml:metaDataProperty><AnyMetaData><adres>г.Нижний Новгород, Ильинская ул., 79/20</adres><telefon>(831)434-40-54</telefon><type>Туристическое агентство</type></AnyMetaData></gml:metaDataProperty><gml:Point><gml:pos>43.987301 56.316744</gml:pos></gml:Point><style>#styleTurism</style></GeoObject>
<GeoObject gml:id="2"><gml:name>Azia-travel</gml:name><gml:metaDataProperty><AnyMetaData><adres>г.Нижний Новгород, Гагарина пр.,13</adres><telefon>433-98-68</telefon><type>Туристическое агентство</type></AnyMetaData></gml:metaDataProperty><gml:Point><gml:pos>43.983825 56.303057</gml:pos></gml:Point><style>#styleTurism</style></GeoObject>
<GeoObject gml:id="3"><gml:name>Royal-travel</gml:name><gml:metaDataProperty><AnyMetaData><adres>г.Нижний Новгород, Рождественская ул.,37,оф.15а</adres><telefon>(831) 430-11-57</telefon><type>Туристическое агентство</type></AnyMetaData></gml:metaDataProperty><gml:Point><gml:pos>43.986358 56.32808</gml:pos></gml:Point><style>#styleTurism</style></GeoObject>
<GeoObject gml:id="4"><gml:name>Travels-if</gml:name><gml:metaDataProperty><AnyMetaData><adres>г.Нижний Новгород, Свободы ул., 57, оф. 107</adres><telefon>(831) 273-81-64</telefon><type>Туристическое агентство</type></AnyMetaData></gml:metaDataProperty><gml:Point><gml:pos>43.86708 56.360696</gml:pos></gml:Point><style>#styleTurism</style></GeoObject>
</gml:featureMembers>
    </GeoObjectCollection>
</ymaps>
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста. Что вы меняете, какой результат ожидаете и какой реально получаете?